# How to replace the null valued column with the values store in the list with the corresponding indexes in CSV using python and pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

Check if the value of the cell in some specific row of CLOSE DATE is blank then proceed with formul of adding 3 days to the SOLVED DATE and update the value of the cell

I'm using pandas library and jupyter Notebook as my text editor.

d is the object of my csv file

```py
for index, row in d.iterrows():
    startdate = row["SOLVED DATE"]
    print(index, startdate)
    enddate = pd.to_datetime(startdate) + pd.DateOffset(days=3)
    row["CLOSE DATE"]=enddate
    #d.iloc[index,10]=enddate
    l1.append(enddate)
```

L1 is the list that contains the values in datetime format
and i need to replace the values of the column named "CLOSE DATE" with the values of the L1 and update my csv file accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Stackoverflow Community!

Iterrows() is usually a slow method and should be avoided in most cases. There are a few ways we can do your task.

- Making Two Dataframes = Null DF & Not Null DF and imputing values in the Null DF then merging the two
- Imputing values in the Null Df itself.

As a supplementary on the logic of adding the updated date column. It is as follows.

1. Let's first take the "SOLVED DATE" and store it in a new series,
   let's call it "new_date".
2. Let's Modify the "new_date" by adding 3 days.
3. Once done set this "new_date" as the value of the column you want to be updated.

In terms of code

```
# 1st Method
import pandas as pd

null = d.loc[d['CLOSE DATE'].isna() == True]
not_null = d.loc[d['CLOSE DATE'].isna() != True]
new_date = null['SOLVED DATE]
new_date = pd.to_datetime(new_date) + pd.DateOffset(days=3)
null['CLOSE DATE'] = new_date
d = pd.concat([null not_null], axis = 0)
d = d.reset_index(drop = True)

# 2nd Method
import pandas as pd

new_date = d.loc[d['CLOSE DATE'].isna() == True,'SOLVED DATE]
new_date = pd.to_datetime(new_date) + pd.DateOffset(days=3)
d['CLOSE DATE'] = d['CLOSE DATE'].fillna(new_date)
```